# Wallpaper slide show doesn't change on big time skip

Tags: 16.04, suspend, desktop-background

I'm using the images found in [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/12/8-bit-day-wallpaper-changes-day) but the part on setting the wallpaper doesn't work so I use the one in the comments which is [this one](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SlideshowWallpapers). Yes this is working and the wallpaper changes when I'm using my computer normally like time changes in a normal flow.

But just like this time, last night around 12am I went to lock screen and closed the laptop lid. Then I opened the lid this 8:30am and the lockscreen is the still the image last 12am (the moon in the highest peak). Then I logged in, but the image doesn't update automatically, I still have to click theme in `Appearance` to `refresh` the wallpaper.

Is this normal? Or anyway to fix this?

My xml file is just like the one in the first link, except the directory of the files are changes to accommodate the second link.

Comment: How long did you wait before deciding it doesn't work? It can't change the wallpaper while your laptop is sleeping of course.

Comment: I waited around more or less 30 seconds. I changed selected the theme right away on the `Appearance` setting